# Dividing with variables on a first level

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was looking over some problems about how to divide with variables. My teacher  prepared us a little by learning how to multiply before the class was over. I got an idea of how this works, but I wanted to learn a problem like this so I would be ahead of my class when I start it again. Is it ok if I see how this problem is solved. I would like to see it to see if it is similar like multiplication or not. Is it ok if I see this.

> Express in simplest form:
>
> $$\frac{1+\frac3x}{1-\frac5x-\frac{24}{x^2}}$$

Comment: @cirpis. Can we multiply $(1+3/x)(1-(5/x)-(24/x^2)$? I have not learned anything like this yet. It was just a glimpse because the class is done with

Comment: I am trying to teach myself now

Comment: We can multiply, but ask the question, do we have to if we are dividing? its more about factoring out common factors here.

Answer (score 2):

We note that your expression can be written as:

$$\frac{1+\frac{3}{x}}{1-\frac{5}{x}-\frac{24}{x^{2}}}=\frac{\frac{1}{x}(x+3)}{\frac{1}{x^{2}}(x^{2}-5x-24)}=\frac{x^{2}(x+3)}{x(x^{2}-5x-24)}=\frac{x(x+3)}{(x^{2}-5x-24)}$$

I hope this helps, if you have more questions don't hesitate to leave a comment.

Comment: @carson for further simplification i advise you read about the quadratic formula and factor the bottom expression. 
$$\frac{x(x+3)}{(x+3)(x-8)}=\frac{x}{x-8}$$

Comment: I did not understand the two last parts because I did try some of it based on some of my knowledge, but after seeing this I got it now. Thank you.

Comment: A useful alternative to factoring out powers of $x$ from the numerator and denominator would be to note that the least common denominator of $3/x, 5/x$, and $24/x^2$ is $x^2$. Once you know the least common denominator is $x^2$, it can save you some initial factoring by multiplying the original expression by $x^2/x^2$, and then distribute.

Answer (score 0):

The way that I simplify expressions like these is to multiply by one as follows (note: $x^2/x^2 = 1$)
$$\frac{1+\frac{3}{x}}{1 - \frac{5}{x} - \frac{24}{x^2}} \cdot \frac{x^2}{x^2} = \frac{x^2+3x}{x^2 - 5x - 24}$$

Now its just a matter of factoring the top and bottom and performing any neccessary cancelations.